# Screen freeze/black screen after installing Nvidia drivers (16.04)

Tags: drivers, 16.04, nvidia, graphics, gpu-driver

> - Videocard: GTX 560
> - NVIDIA drivers installed: nvidia-367 (recommended for my card).
> - OS: Xubuntu 16.04

Problem description:
 Video card works perfectly while using X.org drivers, but after installing Nvidia's, I get a black screen or a freeze on the "decrypt HDD" screen.

I have tried various fixes I've found on the site, from setting "nomodeset" to trying every single driver available to "update-initramfs -u" various times. Recovery mode also works; checked with "lspci -v" and it properly runs the driver.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the issue through a complete reinstall of the OS. Some research showed that the current Nvidia drivers have issues with encrypted drives, so I took encryption and Logic Volumes off during the reinstallation.

Answer (score 0):

Some troubleshoot tips are available at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia#Troubleshooting among which one relates to encryption.

Look up the section 'Driver not active'